# Exception on printing: The device is not ready

Tags: c#, printing, win32exception

I have a report document created by Microsoft Reporting but instead of using its viewer to show the document and print it, I used PrintDocument class to print it directly without showing user any windows.

It worked perfectly until I installed a thermal printer and disabled its Spooler. Now once in a while i receive a Win32Exception indicating **"The Device is not ready"**. I suppose this is because of the Spooler which I have disabled but because of a problem with the printer, I cannot enable it.

So, am I right about the problem? If so, is there anyways to check the printer before sending the print command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PRINTER_INFO_2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162845(VS.85).aspx) structure returned by [GetPrinter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144911(VS.85).aspx) should return the printer status.  The Microsoft Knowledgebase Article "[How to get the status of a printer and a print job](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160129)" includes example code written in C.